# A/B testing for mobile apps?

Tags: usability, iphone, ab-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to A/B test a published IOS and Android app on actual users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/how-to-a-b-test-a-published-ios-and-android-app-on-actual-users)

Is there any proper way and tool to do A/B testing in mobile apps to find the users' engagement and pain points ?

I have read very few things about them, so it will be really nice if someone can share, if they have done something like this on their iPhone/android apps.

Answer (score 3):

TestflightApp.com has an SDK where you can track user sessions and set triggers and events to be fired. This is what I use for AB'ish tests since I already use Testflight to juggle my beta testers.

Also, both Google and Optimizely are working on their own tools for this specific purpose, but that is in closed beta at the moment, with no empty seats.

Answer (score 1):

While I cant say I have done A/B testing on mobile apps before. Take a look at [Zurbs Verify App](http://verifyapp.com/). For a very small fee they allow you to setup A/B and other types of user testing. Test can then be made public through them, integrated into your website via thier JavaScript bar, or distributed by yourself via a link. If you really need of user testing on a particular screen; you can also buy user tests. Not sure how well this section of the site works as my company tend to make test public and after a few days we get more than enough results.