# How to A/B test a published IOS and Android app on actual users?

Tags: android, iphone, usability-testing, ab-testing

I've published several apps on IOS and Android adding flurry to measure the interaction that is happening in those apps, however, I'd love to enhance this interaction and make my apps more useful by using A/B Testing on users who are already using the app, however, I couldn't find any source that does such a thing on mobile apps, I wonder if there are any way to do it.

Comment: I've seen several apps on Android use a "beta" app that allows easy A/B testing of new features vs the main release

Comment: But as he said, his app is already in the App Store / Production, and he wants to test it on existing users. So I think there is no question of a "Beta" app..

Comment: @aliasgar I'm talking published apps; the iOS App Store probably won't let you, but the Android Market definitely allows "beta" versions of otherwise published apps you can publish publicly. It's not "beta" as it "pre release" but beta as in "these features aren't in the main build yet"

Comment: @BenBrocka oh okie, misunderstood. But the answer I published was correct, and It works for iOS also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I would do to have A/B Testing done on Existing Customers / People who already have my app:

- Both the flows of the App you have in mind should be bundled as a part of the same app.
- You use the code injection to send information to Flurry.
- Use the same method to check how many users have downloaded the latest version of your App with both flow experiences A & B.
- For every user who downloads the newest version, update the App with an alternate flag status, and the flag would determine which flow would unlock in the App.
- The rest Flurry would do for you, it will send you the analytics / usage stats for you to decide which one is preferred or has better experience or better usability.
- I am attaching an image which will explain things better.

[image: AB Testing Diagram for Above Explanation]

Answer (score 4):

If you're still looking for a way to do this, I've created an iOS Client Library and PHP Server for performing data-driven A/B Split Tests in your iOS Apps - it should give a kick-start to anybody's Mobile A/B testing effort. There are controls (extending UIButton) for A/B testing button text and images as well as the ability to generically split test String values.

Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/chrismaddern/iOS-Split-A-B-Test-Library).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few players out there who provide a/b testing tools (and new ones seem to be springing up every other day)

Some worth checking out are Swerve, Artisan and Appiterate.

From the looks of it, Artisan and Appiterate are providing some sort of a visual editor for creating a/b tests. Something similar to what Optimizely provides for web. And another post I was going through mentioned that Optimizely was working on it's own solution for mobile. That should be interesting for this space.

Answer (score 0):

There are few recent companies that are enabling you to do this right away e.g.

1) Optimimo - http://www.optimimo.com
2) Arise.io - http://www.arise.io (Clone of Clutch.io bought by Twitter)

There are few others that you will find when you search for Mobile A/B Testing in Google.